# chown to try correct ownership for mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, chown

I have a problem with wordpress. No “Publish” button but “Submit For Review for all post types. To solve this I tried many solutions. The last solution: Correct ownership for mysql data directory or data file saw here: [MySQL error - webhost discussion](https://www.webhostingdiscussion.net/blog/wordpress-2/wordpress-no-publish-submit-for-review.htm)
So, I runned this command and after restart mysql:

> chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

Done this, I have made change to user and group of mysql, (user: mysql, group: mysql), right ?
So, when I try change the mysql user with this new user in wp-config.php, I still  get this message:

> error stabilish a database conection

My doubts:

- The password is changed with this operation ?
- How can I revert this operation ? Or would be better edit wp-config with this changes ? 
  before this operation my user was "wtv"

Comment: First check the username and password of the mysql works which specify in the wp-config.php file.

Comment: top or ps can show you witch user mysql-server is really run with. After chown, you may failed to start mysql-server if with wrong user. You can check user in config file, often in /etc/mysql/my.cnf by default.